# Starting a pseudo-terminalized background process remotely from Python using SSH and Cron

Tags: python, linux, ssh, cron, remote-server

As you can probably tell from the title, I have a fairly convoluted process that I can't seem to get working. I have a python script which starts a remote server (an AWS instance to be specific) and then has to launch a worker thread on that machine. I use Subprocess to do an SSH call in the script, and use screen to start the worker in the background on the remote machine. Screen (afaik) needs a pseudo-terminal to run, so I use SSH's '-t' option.

This works fine when I run the script from the command line, but when I try to run the process from a Cron job, Cron isn't running it in terminal mode, which seems to cause the remote screen session to exit immediately. I tried to substitute nohup and & for screen, but no luck either.

I have a Minimal Working Example I can share here

```
import subprocess as sub
ssh = sub.Popen(["ssh", "-t", "-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no", "-i", "some-key.pem",
            "ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "cd ", "/path/to/work", ";",
            "screen", "-S", "mysession", "-L", "rqworker", "--url", 'redis://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6379', "-v", "work_queue"],
            shell=False, stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE)
```

The above is fairly specific, but I think the same issue can actually be reproduced by just trying to echo 'hi' to a text file. i.e.:

```
rqcmd = ' '.join(["ssh", "-t", "-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no", "-i", "some-key.pem",
            "ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "cd ", "/path/to/work", ";",
            "screen", "-S", "echo", "'hi'" ">" "hi.txt"])
```

When I run the above (the 'hi' version) from cron, I don't get 'hi' in hi.txt, rather I get: "must be running from a terminal" (afaik that's Screen complaining).

Does anyone know how I can get around cron's absence of a pseudo-terminal? Or an alternative to Screen (maybe TMux?) that will allow me to keep the background worker alive? (or an alternative to this process in general...)

**EDIT**
So, after reading: http://michaelseiler.net/2013/04/25/cron-jobs-and-ssh-errors-tty-and-sudo/, I decided to try using SSH's '-tt' option to force pseudo-tty allocation. Using this with my 'hi' example led to a new message in hi.txt - "please set a terminal type". So I added setting the $TERM variable to my ssh command (ugh), and would you believe, the worker starts now! 
Here's the new rqworker subprocess call, in all it's hacky glory...

```
ssh = sub.Popen(["ssh", "-t", "-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no", "-i", "some-key.pem",
            "ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "cd ", "/path/to/work", ";and", "set", "-g", "-x", "TERM", "'screen'", ";and",
            "screen", "-S", "mysession", "-L", "rqworker", "--url", 'redis://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6379', "-v", "work_queue"],
            shell=False, stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE)
```

(my instances have fish-shell installed, hence the ';and' and the strange syntax for setting env vars)

The 'hi' example still doesn't work though (although that was the "trivial" MWE). I now get nothing in hi.txt on the remote server. Since that's not fixed yet, I'm hesitant to mark this as the answer yet.

Comment: I think the commands following connection params and options must be quoted, e.g. `ssh -i ... -o... "echo 'hi' > hi.txt"`

Comment: You mean like: "screen", "-S", "echo 'hi' > hi.txt" ? Tried that there, it didn't change the outcome, so it might work, but I've used the other way (wrapping every command in quotes) with subprocess to this point with no issues.

Comment: No, I mean the final command string should look like `ssh -i file.pem [...]  "command1; command2"`.  `[...]` is all other options to pass to ssh client on your side and command1 and command2 are to execute on the remote side.